# reactDOM.render() elements does not display correctly

Tags: reactjs

Learning react basics here is the code which does not displayed the content inside the reactDOM.render() function

code>

```
https://support-tools.com/?bbe57137d1dbd01d#LLKwVmU8RhBMt1lBCK3LXjK6U/xrxLUXvp5WMRDlC2k=
```

Changed above lines from

```
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

To this

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.6/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.6/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
```

No Idea what is wrong with the code

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you trying to go from React `v17` to `v0.14.6` that might not have a `render` method with the same definition as the current one?

Comment: because V17 was also not working, thought might be a good idea to lower the version and try, but V0.14.6 also not working